# Vectorize searching operations

Tags: python, pandas, search

I'm working with to list of names to find the most similar pairs of string of one list to the other

```
best_match = {'name_1':[],'name_2':[]}
for name_1 in first_list:
    similarity = 0
    max_similarity = 0
    for name_2 in second_list:
        similarity =   (difflib.SequenceMatcher(None,name_1,name_2).ratio())
        if similarity > max_similarity:
            max_similarity = similarity
            names_pair = (name_1,name_2)
    best_match['name_1'].append(names_pair[0])
    best_match['name_2'].append(names_pair[1])
```

Is it possible to vectorize this kind of operations using pandas?

Edit:

Currently, I'm not using pandas, I'm just using the standard.

I only have two list of words:

```
list_1 = ['word_1','word_2','word_4']
list_2 = ['adaad','dddda','wxrd_1',vord_2']
```

for that input the word should return:

```
{'name_1':['word_1','word_2'],'name_2':['wxrd_1','vord_2']}
```

Comment: Please provide some form of starting `dataframe` and a desired output. Are you looking to generate new columns for a starting `dataframe`? Please provide more detail.

Comment: @Abdou I update the question

Comment: It's still not clear what you want here. For example, there is no `word_2` in `list_1` or `list_2` but your desired output has `word_2` in it. Also, is your goal to find the closest match of a `list_1` element in `list_2`, and vice-versa?

Comment: @Abdou Yes, I want the closest match.

Comment: While I now understand what you are trying to do, I don't think there is any point in vectorizing here. The idea behind vectorization is so that you can ***apply*** a function/operation to each element of a collection(`list`, `tuple`, `dict`, etc.) without the use of a `for loop`. In this case, you are not applying an operation or function to each element. You are looping through the lists and using the elements to form something else. In any case, you could write a function that takes in a name and then use numpy's `vectorize()` to vectorize the function itself, so you can pass in a list.